# theano hard_sigmoid() breaks gradient descent

Tags: python, theano, gradient-descent

for intents of highlighting the issue lets follow this [tutorial](http://outlace.com/Beginner-Tutorial-Theano/).

---

theano has 3 ways to compute the sigmoid of a tensor, namely [sigmoid](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/nnet.html#tensor.nnet.sigmoid), [ultra_fast_sigmoid](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/nnet.html#tensor.nnet.ultra_fast_sigmoid) and [hard_sidmoid](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/nnet.html#tensor.nnet.hard_sigmoid). It seems using the latter two breaks the gradient descent algorithm.

The conventional sigmoid converges as it should, but the the others have strange inconsistent behaviours. ultra_fast_sigmoid, just throws a straight error when trying to compute the gradient 'Method not defined ('grad', ultra_fast_sigmoid)', whilst hard_sigmoid compiles fine, but fails to converge on the solution.

---

Does anyone know the source of this behaviour? It s not highlighted in the documentation that this should happen and it seems counter intuitive.

---

code:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import theano.tensor.nnet as nnet
import numpy as np

x = T.dvector()
y = T.dscalar()

def layer(x, w):
    b = np.array([1], dtype=theano.config.floatX)
    new_x = T.concatenate([x, b])
    m = T.dot(w.T, new_x) #theta1: 3x3 * x: 3x1 = 3x1 ;;; theta2: 1x4 * 4x1

    h = nnet.sigmoid(m) ## THIS SIGMOID RIGHT HERE

    return h

def grad_desc(cost, theta):
    alpha = 0.1 #learning rate
    return theta - (alpha * T.grad(cost, wrt=theta))

theta1 = theano.shared(np.array(np.random.rand(3,3), dtype=theano.config.floatX))
theta2 = theano.shared(np.array(np.random.rand(4,1), dtype=theano.config.floatX))

hid1 = layer(x, theta1) #hidden layer

out1 = T.sum(layer(hid1, theta2)) #output layer
fc = (out1 - y)**2 #cost expression

cost = theano.function(inputs=[x, y], outputs=fc, updates=[
        (theta1, grad_desc(fc, theta1)),
        (theta2, grad_desc(fc, theta2))])
run_forward = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=out1)

inputs = np.array([[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[0,0]]).reshape(4,2) #training data X
exp_y = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0]) #training data Y
cur_cost = 0
for i in range(2000):
    for k in range(len(inputs)):
        cur_cost = cost(inputs[k], exp_y[k]) #call our Theano-compiled cost function, it will auto update weights
    if i % 500 == 0: #only print the cost every 500 epochs/iterations (to save space)
        print('Cost: %s' % (cur_cost,))

print(run_forward([0,1]))
print(run_forward([1,1]))
print(run_forward([1,0]))
print(run_forward([0,0]))
```

---

i changed the following lines from the code to make the output shorter for this post (they differ from the tutorial, but are already contained in the code above):

```
from theano.tensor.nnet import binary_crossentropy as cross_entropy #imports
fc = cross_entropy(out1, y) #cost expression
for i in range(4000): #training iteration
```

---

sigmoid

```
Cost: 1.62724279493
Cost: 0.545966632545
Cost: 0.156764560912
Cost: 0.0534911098234
Cost: 0.0280394147992
Cost: 0.0184933786794
Cost: 0.0136444190935
Cost: 0.0107482836159
0.993652087577
0.00848194143055
0.990829396285
0.00878482655791
```

ultra_fast_sigmoid

```
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    (theta1, grad_desc(fc, theta1)),
  File "test.py", line 19, in grad_desc
    return theta - (alpha * T.grad(cost, wrt=theta))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 545, in grad
    grad_dict, wrt, cost_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 1283, in _populate_grad_dict
    rval = [access_grad_cache(elem) for elem in wrt]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 1241, in access_grad_cache
    term = access_term_cache(node)[idx]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 951, in access_term_cache
    output_grads = [access_grad_cache(var) for var in node.outputs]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 1241, in access_grad_cache
    term = access_term_cache(node)[idx]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 951, in access_term_cache
    output_grads = [access_grad_cache(var) for var in node.outputs]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 1241, in access_grad_cache
    term = access_term_cache(node)[idx]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 951, in access_term_cache
    output_grads = [access_grad_cache(var) for var in node.outputs]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 1241, in access_grad_cache
    term = access_term_cache(node)[idx]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 951, in access_term_cache
    output_grads = [access_grad_cache(var) for var in node.outputs]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 1241, in access_grad_cache
    term = access_term_cache(node)[idx]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 951, in access_term_cache
    output_grads = [access_grad_cache(var) for var in node.outputs]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 1241, in access_grad_cache
    term = access_term_cache(node)[idx]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 1089, in access_term_cache
    input_grads = node.op.grad(inputs, new_output_grads)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/elemwise.py", line 662, in grad
    rval = self._bgrad(inputs, ograds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/elemwise.py", line 737, in _bgrad
    scalar_igrads = self.scalar_op.grad(scalar_inputs, scalar_ograds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scalar/basic.py", line 878, in grad
    self.__class__.__name__)
theano.gof.utils.MethodNotDefined: ('grad', <class 'theano.tensor.nnet.sigm.UltraFastScalarSigmoid'>, 'UltraFastScalarSigmoid')
```

hard_sigmoid

```
Cost: 1.19810193303
Cost: 0.684360309062
Cost: 0.692614056124
Cost: 0.697902474354
Cost: 0.701540531661
Cost: 0.703807604483
Cost: 0.70470238116
Cost: 0.704385738831
0.4901260624
0.486248177053
0.489490785078
0.493368670425
```

Comment: Suggested reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the source code of `hard_sigmoid`:

```
def hard_sigmoid(x):
    """An approximation of sigmoid.
    More approximate and faster than ultra_fast_sigmoid.
    Approx in 3 parts: 0, scaled linear, 1
    Removing the slope and shift does not make it faster.
    """
    # Use the same dtype as determined by "upgrade_to_float",
    # and perform computation in that dtype.
    out_dtype = scalar.upgrade_to_float(scalar.Scalar(dtype=x.dtype))[0].dtype
    slope = tensor.constant(0.2, dtype=out_dtype)
    shift = tensor.constant(0.5, dtype=out_dtype)
    x = (x * slope) + shift
    x = tensor.clip(x, 0, 1)
    return x
```

So it is just implemented as a piecewise linear function, whose gradient is 0.2 within the range of (-2.5, 2.5) and 0 elsewhere. Which means if the input falls outside the region (-2.5, 2.5), its gradient will be zero, and no learning will happen.

So it might not be appropriate for training, but can be use for approximating the prediction result.

---

Edit:
To evaluate the gradient of the network parameters, normally we use [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation).
Here's a very simple example.

```
x = theano.tensor.scalar()
w = theano.shared(numpy.float32(1))
y = theano.tensor.nnet.hard_sigmoid(w*x)  # y=w*x, w is initialized to 1.

dw = theano.grad(y, w)  # gradient wrt w, which is equal to slope*x in this case
net = theano.function([x], [y, dw])

print net(-3)
print net(-1)
print net(0)
print net(1)
print net(3)

Output:
[array(0.0), array(-0.0)]  # zero gradient because the slope is zero
[array(0.3), array(-0.2)]
[array(0.5), array(0.0)]  # zero gradient because x is zero
[array(0.7), array(0.2)]
[array(1.0), array(0.0)]  # zero gradient because the slope is zero
```

---

EDIT BY OP:
`ultra_hard_sigmoid` fails, if you look at the source code implementation, because it is hard-coded in python and not handled by tensor expressions.

Comment: that doesn't make sense... the learning happens on the weights of network not the activation function, even if all neurons in a previous layer would only output 1, T.grad will find weight gradient values wrt a loss function. In gradient descent, the sigmoid output is treated as no more than a constant

Comment: @user2255757 The gradient of the activation function will affect what happens before the activation function in the forward pass, not after. I made a typo in the original post (changed "output" to "input"), maybe that's what has been confusing. I've added some code to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: Of course you are right, thank you for highlighting it in such a simple manner and apologies for "correcting" you with my flawed reasoning.